# Authenicate users of our web app against client's active directory using LDAP.

Tags: authentication, ldap

A new client has required us to authenticate login users to our web, iOS and android apps against his active directory using LDAP. He wants to control the grouping of his users so as to control the permissions. i.e. admin, manager, staff. etc. I've searched it and am lost as to even know where to start. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What is the application written in? .net, java, ...

Comment: We have the prototype using Symfony/Angular2/Ionic for the mobile clients. We are discussing a Windows laptop app with the client and that's when the LDAP/AD conversation started.

Comment: You should NOT expose LDAP repository to the Internet. OpenID Connect would be the best current practice to implement for the requirements you have presented.